# Your code is showing!

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I go to [Should I feed hot dogs to my dachshund?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/what-are-the-consequences-if-my-dachshund-eats-a-hot-dog)

I get:

`fore(qc, s); var sc=document.createElement('script'); sc.async=true; sc.src=(ssl?'https://sb':'http://b') + '.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s); })(); _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "17440561" }); _qevents.push({ qacct: "p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc" });`

This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Are you browsing in [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) by any chance?!

Comment: It is gone already...

Comment: yup gone already. But no I was in IE.

Comment: wait... it's back!

Comment: In IE it shows up but in chrome it give a user friendly error

Comment: I need to know what happens!

Comment: The question is closed.

Comment: Screenshots might be helpful to show exactly what you are/were seeing where. (A reasonable amount of) screenshots never / rarely hurt in bug reports.

Comment: I don't see any errors or code on the page. If this happens again, can you add a screenshot to this post and let me know? Thanks!

Comment: I think this can be closed out. It was happening on and off the day I posted it but now I've checked it and it isn't happening at all. If it happens again I'll grab a screenshot.